# Does it make sense to bundle images with the Grails Asset Pipeline?

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline

Ok, so this may be a stupid question... but I don't see any examples that show bundling images.  I noticed our round trips to the server drop dramatically when using bundling - but only for css/js files.  Does it make sense to bundle images?

Comment: How would you "bundle" images? They are individual files. Now, if you are using the images only through CSS you can combine them all into a single image and using CSS only show parts of the larger single image. A similar technique has been used for decades in video games.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to think of some sort of pre-loading strategy so they'd be fetched from the browser cache when the page really needed one.  But I don't know how you'd do it without some magic to split them back out on the client side.  Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious.

Comment: Nope, the asset pipeline doesn't support any type of image bundling or pre-loading.

Comment: Thanks, that's at least the confirmation I was looking for.  If you post it as the answer I'll give you credit.

Comment: Answer added, per request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asset pipeline for Grails doesn't have the ability to combine multiple images or allow for pre-loading.

There are many other techniques that you could use to accomplish this (CSS sprites and image stitching, Javascript pre-loaders, etc.) but none of them are part of the asset pipeline for Grails.